# Getting error when I use theme.breakpoints.up in styles for Class Components in React

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I've this following code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Button } from "@material-ui/core";
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/styles';

const styles = theme => ({
   buttonStyles: {
       color: 'blue',
       border:'3px solid green',
       [theme.breakpoints.up('sm')]: {
           color: 'red'
       }
   }
});

class MaterialButton extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
}
render() {
    let { classes } = this.props;
    console.log("*I*");
    console.log(this);
    console.log(this.props);
    return (
        <div>
            <FirstButton>FirstClickHere</FirstButton>
            <Button className={classes.buttonStyles}>Click here</Button>
        </div>
    )
 }
}

MaterialButton.propsType = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired
}
export default withStyles(styles)(MaterialButton);
```

Problem is I'm getting this error only when I use Class components.
[image]
Do I have to pass any argument to the styles from the component? I'm very much new to this, so trying to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to access the default theme, you can do

```js
...
import { createMuiTheme } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const theme = createMuiTheme();
const styles = {
  buttonStyles: {
    color: "blue",
    border: "3px solid green",
    [theme.breakpoints.up("sm")]: {
      color: "red"
    }
  }
};
```

**Edit:** Your code will work if you import `withStyles` through `@material-ui/core` and not on `@material-ui/styles`.

```js
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core";
```

[image: Edit condescending-drake-d0l3j]